# Php Embedded tableau report is not showing in safari

Tags: php, tableau-api

I Embedded a tableau report in my web page using php. I works fine in Chrome and Firefox. But not loading the page in safari.
My code is like this,

```
<embed src="{{ $tableauLink }}" width="100%" height="600px" type="application/pdf">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be using an older version of safari. Try it on an updated version. This solved my problem.